# How much physics is necessary for learning Electronics?

Tags: books

i am a CS student i wanted to enter the field of "Internet Of Things", got a recommended book "Art of electronics" now my physics base is school level but my Calculus 1 is pretty rock solid so i have two options right now:

1> Read Feynman vol 1 & 2 and then start Art of electronics?

2> Just start Art of electronics along with Multi-variable calculus?

which option might help me get the core of electronics subject and most out of Art of electronics book? Since i do not know what electronics heavily rely on help from professionals is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: *i wanted to enter the field of "Internet Of Things"* That is a very vague statement. What do you want to do there ? Why suddenly the interest in electronics while you're a CS student ? If you want to learn electronics, become an EE. Realize that you cannot learn "everything". Find a field you like and become an expert in it. You have already chosen CS. There are still many CS things you can do related to IOT. And btw, IOT is a hype now, it's never a good idea to invest too much into a hype. You better learn skills that you will also need in 10 years when IOT is old hat.

Comment: It depends on what kind of electronics you want to do. If you want to master [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/240747/simulation-model-for-floating-gate), you'd better know physics pretty well. If you only want to make digital stuff with some simple MCU, not much. I'm afraid this is off-topic anyway.

Comment: okay i understand what you are saying but i wanted to understand micro-controllers and how they work...i am not talking about career wise, see i get lots of spare time like 6 hours and electronics was my hobby since childhood, but now i want to understand the core of it in my spare time so please if you can help?

Comment: Then, you don't need to read any physics book yet. Read some tutorials about Arduino, that's what you want, I guess.

Comment: i already did all of the stuff from arduino starter kit and some projects with arduino.

Comment: *electronics was my hobby since childhood* AHA ! Same here, what I did is just read everything electronics related which I could  got my hands on. If something doesn't interest you (for example, too much physics) simply skip it ! You will soon enough find out what is relevant for you wand what is not. If you want to know how the transistors in an Arduino work, read a book about CMOS electronics. If not, just use the Arduino and be happy :-)

Comment: @user3236961 "To **learn electronics ... how-much**"? obviously as much you  could. required Basic school-Level physics and chemistry is required. (On syllabus and course at your country, I don't know); but it is not important how-much thing you learn, important is how deep you learn.  Also, you need to apply "common-sense". Many **nearly-uneducated workers show near-magic, just with common-sense**. In other-hand, learning physics without  understanding, would just would become burden. **However, physics lesson would help deal terms, units, phenomena,mechanisms etc without blind memorization**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3, start with the Horowitz. :-)

If you want to understand the "behind the scene" you need a lot of physics. You need some notions of modern physics, quantum mechanics, for understand Fermi Levels, tunnel effect, photodiode, etc.
If you want to have an idea you should take a look at "*Milmann - Halkias*", the opening chapters and chapter 19 (about solid state physics), or the venerable *Sze* "*Physics of semiconductors devices*".

But for became a maker (a good maker), in my humble opinion, you don't need so much. The "Art of Electronics" require a very small knowledge of physics and math, it has a very practical approach, intuitive, and could give you a robust preparation in design electronic circuit.

Comment: yes i want to be "maker" so calculus 1 is sufficient for "Art of electronics"?

Comment: You only need complex maths if you want to become an EE, for hobby stuff simple calculations usually suffice. So don't worry about it.

Comment: @user3236961,  FakeMoustache Paul responded well to you, I would just add that the book has an appendix with the mathematical knowledge needed, and you will see for yourself what is required.

Comment: @Antonio i looked at the appendix and in the preface the author clearly stated that "for the sake of this book solid state physics explanations have been omitted" well that a relief. Complex math is okay with me, thanks